# 'Case Is' NOT with multiple not criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Select Case, Case is statements in my VBA code, such as Case is > 250 or Case is < 18.  When an item that meets that criteria, my code copies that specific item and pastes it to a new range. However I have a column containing states of Australia (NSW, VIC, QLD, WA, SA, NT, ACT, TAS).  All these are ok, but if a time comes where there is text that is not a state, I want to also copy and paste it to a new range, but I do not know what that text will be.  I therefore need a code that says, Case is (if not an Australian State) copy item to new range.

Any ideas? I have the section that will do the copy and paste ok, unless the statement has to change quite a bit.

Comment: I have scoured the interned but no joy, I have tried using <> "state", .... but that just returns all the states I have listed.

Comment: why can't you use `case else`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column containing all genuine states of Australia or any sheet the you can try referring to that range using if..then..else in case statement. That way you can copy the text in new range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opposite logic implementing `Select Case`.

Put all the values in the `Select Case`, if they meet that criteria do nothing, and perform your Copy>>Paste in the `Case Else` section.

```
Select Case Aust_States ' let's assume this is your variable for Australia States
    Case "NSW", "VIC", "QLD", "WA", "SA", "NT", "ACT", "TAS"
        ' do nothing

    Case Else
        ' do your copy>>paste here

End Select
```